# Fancybox on html

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

Is it possible to open fancybox window from within the html?

meaning:

```
 <button onclick=("open fancybox here")>Fancybox</button>
```

Is there any way of doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: http://fancybox.net/howto  If those instructions aren't working for you, you need to be far more descriptive in your posts here to get useful help.

Comment: @Brad i couldn't find any reference to how to use fancybox within the html file not using jquery or another file... and its kinda hard to explain it more than i did.

Comment: Fancybox requires jQuery, doesn't it?  It was my understanding that it was built with it.

Comment: From the Fancybox home page:  "FancyBox is a tool for displaying images, html content and multi-media in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page. 
It was **built using the jQuery library**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why would you want to mix your markup with javascript but anyway, here's an example:

```
<button onclick="$.fancybox({ type: 'iframe', href: 'http://bbc.com' })">Fancybox</button>
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8N2aV/2/).